# CSS / JS stretch table according to height

Tags: jquery, html, css

Suppose `table` has `200px` `height`

Table rows are generated dynamically. If rows are limited or less than height, it will be fit according height. Like this

[200px height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpWhp.jpg)

If rows numbers are increased, than content starts to overflow automatically and table size starts to increase according to the content

[overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmhS1.jpg)

But requirement is to stretch. I am trying to **stretch** table according to **fixed height** instead of content-overflow, whatever numbers of rows, it should be stretched in provided height. For example : within `200px` in here

[Stretched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBH8T.jpg)

I had tried nesting table with div.

```
#table_container{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
}
#table_container table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

But has not been stretched.

For image, we can apply `object-fit` -> `cover, fill, contain`

Any CSS method or JS plugin to stretch in specific height ? Not resize..

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>S.N.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Faculty</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Richa</td>
        <td>Science</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Rohan</td>
        <td>MGMT</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Sahil</td>
        <td>Arts</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Rocky</td>
        <td>Lab</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>IT</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to have the table always the same size?

Comment: @csgabriella, exactly

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend that way: if you run into a scenario, where you have hundreds of table rows, your table will become unreadable. Why don't you use [overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) and make it scrollable?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:500px;
  height:100px!important;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>S.N.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Faculty</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Richa</td>
        <td>Science</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Rohan</td>
        <td>MGMT</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Sahil</td>
        <td>Arts</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Rocky</td>
        <td>Lab</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>IT</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```